# How to make a bot edit its own message on Discord

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, message, edit

My friend wrote this amazing code for me but it doesn't seem to work. It's meant to send a message on a command then edit the message over and over again. But when I run the code my terminal says

> DiscordAPIError: Cannot edit a message authored by another user method: 'patch', path: '/channels/808300406073065483/messages/811398346853318668', code: 50005, httpStatus: 403

Is there a way to fix this problem?

```js
client.on('message', userMessage => 
{
    if (userMessage.content === 'hi') 
    {
        botMessage = userMessage.channel.send('hi there')
        botMessage.edit("hello");
        botMessage.edit("what up");
        botMessage.edit("sup");
        botMessage.react(":clap:")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Channel#send()` method returns a promise, meaning you must wait for the action to finish before being able to define it. This can be done using either `.then()` or `async` and `await`. From personal preference, I regularly use the second option, although I have laid both options out for you.

#### Final Code

```
client.on('message', async userMessage => {
  if (userMessage.content === 'hi') 
    {
        /*
          botMessage = await userMessage.channel.send('hi there')
        */
        userMessage.channel.send('hi there').then(botMessage => {
          await botMessage.edit("hello");
          await botMessage.edit("what up");
          botMessage.edit("sup");
          botMessage.react(":clap:")
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Bqre. I tried this and it work perfectly fine thanks to you. Thanks for saving me head scratching time. lol

client.on('message', async userMessage => {
  if (userMessage.content === 'hi') 
    {
       botMessage = await userMessage.channel.send('hi there')
          await botMessage.edit("hello");
          await botMessage.edit("what up");
          botMessage.edit("sup");
          botMessage.react("")
    }
});